# why does mysql say I have an error in my SQL syntax, when I use the command help and status?

Tags: mysql

```
mysql> help;

1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to 
your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 1

mysql> show databases;

+--------------------+
| Database           |
+--------------------+
| information_schema |
| cppp               |
| db_byb_develop     |
| mysql              |
| test               |
| train              |
+--------------------+

6 rows in set

mysql> status

-> ;

1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to 
your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'status' at line 1
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its

```
SHOW STATUS;
```

not just

```
status ;
```

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/show-status.html